# Can I use code blocks in head content and link tags to reference themes?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET app using themes, and I've assigned a theme to the app using the web config.

I have a bookmark icon that I want to use for my page and it is located in the themes directory, but I am having trouble referencing the themes location from a link tag in my header.

First I tried putting a code block inside the link tags href element, which did not work. Instead all it did was HTML encode the <% characters and output it directly to the browser:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/App_Themes/<%=Page.Theme %>/images/bookmark.ico" type="image/x-icon" runat="server"/>
```

I am able to put a code block inside an element in an hr tag though, so I don't know why it won't work in a link tag:

```
<hr test="<%=Page.Theme %>"/>
```

Then I tried doing a Response.Write inside the head tag, but I got an error saying the Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks:

```
<% Response.Write("<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/images/bookmark.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\"/>"); %>
```

I also tried it just with a string literal, and got the same error:

```
<%= "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/App_Themes/" + Page.StyleSheetTheme + "/images/bookmark.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\"/>" %>
```

Is there any way to reference something from the themes directory inside the link tag?

I'm trying to do this in both an ASP.NET 2 and an ASP.NET 2 MVC app.

Comment: Can you show us what is rendered to the browser from your first example?  If your application is stored in a subdirectory, this will bomb because your link points to the root.  If that isn't the problem, the html rendered to the browser will probably hold the key.

Comment: NickLarsen - It will render &lt;%=Page.Theme%> where my code block is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work because you marked it as **runat="server"**

try this instead

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}/images/bookmark.ico", Page.Theme)) %>" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Comment: Does not work either.  Still get the error The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. ).

Comment: can you tell me what your entire <head> tag looks like?

Comment: if you have runat="server" in your head tag and you add any other controls to it you couldn't do what I suggested

Comment: Do you know why runat="server" makes it fail? I would think it would be the other way round

Comment: tags marked with `runat="server"` can't be modified inline since ASP.Net is managing that control.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an HTML helper such as:

```
public static string SetThemeIcon(this HtmlHelper html, string themename)
{
    var filePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/App_Themes/" + themename + "/images/bookmark.ico");
    return "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"" + filePath + "\" type=\"image/x-icon\"/>";
}
```

then, in your view or master page, simply reference it as so:

```
<%= Html.SetThemeIcon("test") %>
```

or as in your case above (in mvc):

```
<%= Html.SetThemeIcon(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Theme) ? Page.StyleSheetTheme : Page.Theme) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the inline code by wrapping your script with some server element:

```
<head runat="server">
   <title>My Test App <title>
   <div runat="server">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/App_Themes/<%=Page.Theme %>/images/bookmark.ico" type="image/x-icon" runat="server"/>
   </div>
</head>
```

Comment: It appears you can put the runat=server on the element, but you can't embedd the binding tags in the middle of the href attribute, as they get rendered out as encoded html.  If I put a ~ at the begining, it does render the app root though.

Answer (score 1):

I use this way. (Add dummy space into block):

`<link href="<%=""+RootUrl%>_ui/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=""+RootUrl%>_ui/favicon.ico" />`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working by using some inline code.  Inline code is not my my first choice but I wanted a solution that worked in mvc as well.  Here's what I came up with:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Test App <title>
    <script language="CS" runat="server">
        void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
        {
            string sTheme = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Theme) ? Page.StyleSheetTheme : Page.Theme;
            litFacIcon.Text = "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/App_Themes/" + sTheme + "/images/bookmark.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\"/>";
        } 
    </script>
    <asp:Literal ID="litFacIcon" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</head>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer if it is the one you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/styles.css") %>";
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/print.css") %>" print;
    </style>
</head>
```